# Automating tasks in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, script, automation, powershell

I need some help automating some tasks in XP. Most of them are of console nature. Now in Linux this probably wouldn't be too difficult to pull off but I'm not too acquainted with Windows automation capabilities. There are couple of scripts I need. I presume there are ways to script this in Windows 7 using Microsoft-DOS but I'm unsure. Just to be clear I'm merely listing what I would need to be done, so you know what feature set I require, I'm not asking to write scripts for me.

Script #1
 1. Zip folder
 2. Add the rest of the folder including the previous zip into SVN.
 3. Open Zip and overwrite some folder.

Script #2
 1. Copy file to a specific folder
 2. Execute that file in a browser

**So what *tool* would allow me to automate these tasks?**

Comment: There are endless number of *tools*.  I guess the question is what are you trying to do??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inbuilt Task Scheduler will allow you to do all that easily (I'm presuming you know how to write simple batch scripts?). In Windows 7 it's accessible through Administrative Tools.

Comment: Only superficially, I know echo and calling programs from command line. Toss a few links about more advanced stuff (e.g. zipping/extracting files in Windows 7) and I'll consider this answered.

Comment: This is a great resource for using 7zip from the command line: http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples

You should be able to just run eg. path_to_firefox.exe <filename>.

Answer (score 2):

If you expect to be automating windows on a regular basis (or even if not really) it would probably be worth the effort to learn [Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419). It is the scripting language that MS plans to move to for automation. Most current MS products (including Operating Systems) already support it and MS has committed to making as many future products as possible support easy automation via Powershell.

Comment: You could also use the Scripting host along with VBScript or JScript.

Comment: You could do that. The only drawback is that you would be spending your time learning technology that MS has said they will no longer be improving as opposed to learning a technology that they have said they will be improving moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

I know Windows 10 has a Task Scheduler, where you can automate when certain tasks are ran. I don't know if older Windows versions have the same tool.

Comment: How is this answering the question?

Comment: Well, I know Windows 10 has it, so normally Windows XP should also have it (but I'm not sure of it). With the task manager you can run your code whenever you want (eery hour, every time at startup, ...). If you have the code, you can automate the process.